# Consume webservice hosted by sharepoint using phonegap android app

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, web-services, cordova

I am developing an android app using phonegap in eclipse.
All the files for this app will be pushed by Sharepoint-2013 on a webservice.
The app should consume this web service and display the updated data(for example, display updated information like news and notices using .html file when an updated .xml file is pushed on the webservice)
So my Question 1 is How exactly to consume this web service using phonegap in eclipse?

Also the app will have a search feature where the user enters a search string in a textfield.
Using this input the app should search the database using the webservice and display results on the app.
So my Question 2 is How to do this? Do I need some backend programming to achieve this? If yes, please guide how to go about it.
Thank you.

PS- I am relatively new to programming and I only know HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT and jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to sharepoint using Javascript and SPServices.
http://spservices.codeplex.com/

There is an active forum with information at that site too!

Comment: I tried looking at the website you mentioned. But I couldnt get any clarity on my doubts.

Comment: Ok....
SPServices is a javascript library that will consume all the webservices you need to connect to Sharepoint from a Javascript environment. There is a JQuery version of the library.

You can use the SPServices search call to search for information/ Notes/ documents. 

Example search: http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/example-of-using-the-spservices-search-web-service/